# Is there a map which shows all the black holes in our galaxy?

Tags: black-holes, astronomy, resource-recommendations, milky-way

I am looking for a map which shows all black holes in the Milky Way.

See this exoplanet map for what I mean.
[image]

If it is not existing (yet). Is there at least an online catalogue which summarizes for all black holes which have been discovered so far?

Comment: I don't know that there is a compiled list, but there are papers about observations of BH candidates (e.g., [this one from 2001 in MNRAS](http://mnras.oxfordjournals.org/content/331/4/1065.full)).

Comment: @Kyle, that's all?! Guess, we are still in the "James Cook age" of cosmology ;). Time for more bachelor theses on this topic!!

Comment: @RandyWelt: I'm sure there's more recent work done, that's one of the first Google hits I got when searching *coordinates galactic black holes -supermassive*. It's surprisingly hard to find something that doesn't emit light ;)

Comment: Such a list cannot exist until either we go well beyond the solar system or we come into contact with others. Thanks to the galaxy's central bulge and its many bands of gas, a sizable portion of the galaxy is completely hidden from view.

Comment: To nail a black hole you need it's mass and there are still only of order 10 BHs with secure masses well above 3 solar. Many candidates from X-ray surveys though. There could easily be 100 million in our Galaxy...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this would be better for astronomy.SE.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open because astronomy & astrophysics questions are fully on topic here.